# Regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

here is the code

```
var str = 'a girl is reading a book!';
var reg =  /\w*(?=ing\b)/g;
var res = str.match(reg);
console.log(res);
```

result is ["read",""] in chrome.

I wanna ask why there is "" in the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected behaviour

First `read` is captured since it is followed by `ing`.Here `ing` is only matched..It is never included in the result.

Now we are at the position after `read` i.e we would be at `i`..here again `ing` matches(*due to `\w*`*) and it gives an **empty result** because there is nothing **between** read and ing.

You can use `\w+(?=ing\b)` to avoid the empty result

Answer (score 2):

`/\w*(?=ing\b)/g` 
Here you are using `*` which means none or more, Hence it captures both `"read"ing` and `""ing` after it reads the `read` part. Use + for one or more.